# To install Tensorflow via Cmd Command?

Tags: python, cmd, tensorflow2.0

When installing TensorFlow via the command line:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

I receive the following error message:

> ```
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
> ERROR: Tensorflow's matching distribution could not be located.
> ```

I anticipate having Tensorflow installed on my system.

Comment: Are you using Python 3.12? If yes, that is the problem, you have to downgrade to 3.11

Answer (score 0):

You system might lack some of the requirements. Check for hardware and software requirements for tensorflow in this URL: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip.

If your system is compatible try these steps:

- **Update pip**: Ensure that your pip version is up to date by running:

  ```
        pip install --upgrade pip
  ```
- **Specify Version**: You can try specifying a specific version:

  ```
        pip install tensorflow==<version>
  ```
- **Use a Virtual Environment**: Create a new virtual environment and try installing TensorFlow within that environment. Sometimes, conflicts with other packages can cause installation issues. Conda environment is my suggestion for ML projects. (conda installation: https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html). You can also use Python's default virtual environment `venv`

  ```
        conda create --name myProject python=3.9
        conda activate myProject
  ```

Comment: Only the pip install --upgrade pip command runs smoothly; the others don't...

Comment: What error do you get when running `pip install tensorflow==2.10`?

Also, did you try creating virtual environment?

Provide more details on the question like python version, pip version, system configurations, etc. that you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

try this for for Python 2. x :

```
pip install --index-url=https://pypi.org/simple/ tensorflow
```

try this for for Python 3. x :

```
pip3 install --index-url https://pypi.org/simple/ tensorflow
```

See also pip install documentation:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/

Answer (score 0):

Latest python version of 3.12 don't support for tenserflow